# "While" and "do while" validation for a "for" loop

Tags: java

Edit: The user enters a positive number and the code goes from that number to 1. For example the user enters an 8, so it goes 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

The logic part is working. I'm having problems validating the user from entering a negative number.

This is what I have but it's not working.

```
String stringSeries = "";

    int userInput = userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number to evaluate"));  

    for (int i = 1; userInput >= i; userInput--) 
    {
       while (userInput <= 0)
        {
            userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a valid number"));  
        }

      stringSeries +=userInput+ ", ";
    }
    System.out.println(stringSeries);
```

When I enter a negative number the program says "build successful" while it should ask again to enter a positive number.

Also, how could I do it with a do while?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you're **trying** to do?

Comment: Please provide what you wanted to do . Just writing its not working will not let us understand what you wanted to perform

Comment: Ok, the user enter a positive number and the code goes from that number to 1. For example the user enters an 8, so it goes 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

Comment: The `while` loop is doing nothing, because the `for` loop has already checked that `userInput` is positive.

Comment: Place the `while` loop where you're asking for the input number instead of inside the `for` loop.  Initialize `userInput` to a negative number so that you're sure the `while` loop will execute so that the `JOptionPane` will pop up.   Or, you can use a `do-while` construct as you suggested.  Putting it inside the `for` loop doesn't make sense.  You also need to start your `for` loop with `int i = userInput`, and make sure the loop iterates as long as `userInput >= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your intentions correctly, you are trying to read in an integer, verify that it is greater than 0, and then print out all numbers from that number down to 1 in descending order.

If this is the case, the issue lies in the placement of your while loop. The condition on the for loop is userInput >= i. You have assigned a value of 1 to i. Given this, if userInput <= 0 (your condition for the while loop), the code within the for loop will never be executed (as userInput >= i, or equivalently userInput >= 1, is never true). The correction would be to move the while statement before your for loop, making it:

```
String stringSeries = "";

int userInput = userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number to evaluate"));  

while (userInput <= 0)
{
    userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a valid number"));  
}

for (int i = 1; userInput >= i; userInput--) 
{
  stringSeries +=userInput+ ", ";
}
System.out.println(stringSeries);
```

A few comments on structure and idioms: the second userInput in your assignment is unnecessary. Typically in for loops, i (your iteration variable) is the value being changed. A more idiomatic way of doing this would be:

```
String stringSeries = "";

int userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number to evaluate"));  

while (userInput <= 0)
{
    userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a valid number"));  
}

for (int i = userInput; i >= 1; i--) 
{
  stringSeries += i+ ", ";
}
System.out.println(stringSeries);
```

If you wanted to use a do while loop, the code would be:

```
String stringSeries = "";

int userInput;    
do {
    userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a valid number"));  
} while(userInput <= 0);

for (int i = userInput; i >= 1; i--) 
{
  stringSeries += i+ ", ";
}
System.out.println(stringSeries);
```

Comment: Pretty much what I said!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
int userInput = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive number to evaluate"));        
 do{
     System.out.print(userInput + ",");
   }while(--userInput > 0);
```

Comment: No. This would terminate the program if the user entered a negative number. The OP wants to keep asking for a number until a positive one is inserted.